# Need help in projected area of pipe along the direction of flow

Tags: matlab

I have modeled pipe and elbow using MATLAB (Please see Fig. 1 below). Have some confusion how to calculate the projected area of the element of pipe and elbow. For instance, if water is flowing in Z direction, elements of pipe1 and pipe 3 will not experience any pressure and force, while pipe 2, elbow 1 and elbow 2 will experience water pressure and corresponsidng forces. I was told that I have to calculate projected length and width and multiply to get projected area. This area will be such that when water is flowing in Z direction, corresponding area of pipe 1 and pipe 3 will be zero and there would be area for the remaining parts.

[image: Fig. 1]

My code is as follows:

```
%% element area pipe 1
for m = 1:size(element_num_shell_1_1,2) 
% size(element_num_shell_1_1,2) = 840, total number of elements of pipe 1
    if mod(m,n_ele_circum-1)~= 0 
% n_ele_circum = number of elements around the circumference = 15
        P1 = node_coord_list(m,[2:4]); % 
        Q1 = node_coord_list(m+1,[2:4]);
        R1 = node_coord_list(m+(n_ele_circum-1),[2:4]);
    else
        P1 = node_coord_list(m,[2:4]);
        Q1 = node_coord_list(m-(n_ele_circum-2),[2:4]);
        R1 = node_coord_list(m+(n_ele_circum-1),[2:4]);
    end
    if flow_direction == 1 % flow_direction =1 means flow paralle to + Z axis
        l = abs(P1(1)-Q1(1)); % length
        w = abs(P1(2)-R1(2)); % width
      elseif flow_direction == 2 % flow_direction =2 means flow paralle to + X axis
         l = abs(P1(3)-Q1(3)); % length
        w = abs(P1(2)-R1(2)); % width
    end
    Area_ele(m) = l*w; 
 end
```

Here, P1, Q1 and R1 are as follows in Fig. 3:

[image: Fig. 3]

The problem is that, for pipe 1 and pipe 3, I got zero area, however, for pipe 2 and elbow also I got zero projected area. Can anyone help me in this regards? Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and edit your question in that way, that your code is not added as a figure but as code directly into your question. Also see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)